# Rails4 NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: json, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-data

Hello I'm getting the error below by using Rails 4. My front-end(EmberJs) provides json.

Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-30 00:54:18 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"article"=>{"title"=>"Title", "body"=>"Content", "author_id"=>"2", "author"=>nil}}
Unpermitted parameters: author
Completed 500  in 4782ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:43:in`block in create'
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:42:in `create'

My Model looks like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :title, presence: true
 validates :body, presence: true

 attr_accessible :title, :body, :author_id

 belongs_to :author
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @article = Article.new
      respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @article }
      end
    end

   def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.json { render json: @article, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.json { render json: @article, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :author_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is line 43 in your articles controller? The one you posted doesn't even have 43 lines. Also, why are you using attr_accessible in your model, but strong parameters in your controller?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with attr_accesible but it does'nt works. the line 43(it's an extract of the controller) corresponds to the call of strong parameters @article = Article.new(article_params). What I don't understand is why and when it tries to access to the array and gets undefined method []' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing 
gem 'protected_attributes' from gemfile.